# linear algebra exams preparation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Hello guys I have two simple tasks in linear algebra I have to figure out how to solve.

Vector $a = (k,1,k+1)$
Vector $b = (-1,2,1-k)$

Question 1: For which value of $k$ is the length ob vector $a +  b$ the same length as vector $a - b$? Is $k=1$ correct?

Question 2: For which values of $k$ are the vectors $a + b$ and $a - b$ orthogonal?

Thanks a lot guys!

**Edit added**: for the first question I calculated vector ${\underline{a}+\underline{b}}$ and ${\underline{a}-\underline{b}}$ and then calculated the norms which I equated. for the second question I calculated vector ${\underline{a}+\underline{b}}$ and ${\underline{a}-\underline{b}}$ again and now calculated the scalar product which I equated to zero. Problem is I don't even know if this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit the question and add some sort of solution attempt. That way, it'll be more helpful for you when someone answers (since they can correct you, and thus hopefully correct any misunderstanding)

Comment: for the first question I calculated vector a+ b and a-b and then calculated the norms which I equated. for the second question I calculated vector a+ b and a-b again and now calculated the scalar product which I equated to zero. Problem is I don't even know if this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: I have copied and pasted your solution attempt to your question. Can you please confirm the vectors ${\underline{a}}$ and ${\underline{b}}$? It's difficult to tell what they are from the question

Comment: Your approach is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yes that's correct

Comment: As @Tortar said - this approach is indeed correct :D